# How do I get the index of a type matching some predicate?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a variadic list of types and I want to find the index of the first type that has a base of type `Base`. If it cannot find this, it should return `-1`. This is how I would like to do it:

```
typedef std::tuple<A, B, C> Tuple;

int idx = find_if<std::is_base_of, Base, Tuple>::value;
```

Where `std::is_base_of` is the predicate, `Base` is its argument and the tuple are the elements to check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about

```
constexpr std::size_t npos = -1;

template <template <class T> class, typename, std::size_t pos = 0>
struct find_if;

template <template <class T> class Pred, typename T, std::size_t pos, typename... tail>
struct find_if<Pred, std::tuple<T, tail...>, pos> :
    std::conditional<Pred<T>::value,
                     std::integral_constant<std::size_t, pos>,
                     find_if<Pred, std::tuple<tail...>, pos+1>>::type {};

template <template <class T> class Pred>
struct find_if<Pred, std::tuple<>> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, npos> {};

template <template <class, class> class T, class U>
struct bind
{
    template <class X>
    using first  = T<U, X>;
    template <class X>
    using second = T<X, U>;
};
```

Use like this:

```
find_if<bind<std::is_base_of, Base>::first, Tuple>::value
```

#### [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e069da348c5e9769).

Comment: What made you choose `int64_t` as the type to return?

Comment: @0x499602D2 I actually wanted to change it to `size_t` but forgot. Did it now.

Comment: Since `std::size_t` is unsigned, you'll get overflow assigning it `-1`. Is that still alright?

Comment: @0x499602D2 Yes, that's absolutely fine. [conv.integral]. Did you never see this before?

Comment: @Columbo Sure I have, but I was using your code to find an element in a tuple using `std::tuple_element`. If `find_if` returned `-1` then the result of the overflow will match an incomplete specialization because of the overflow. I guess I have to find a way around that.